# Which language to use for custom Gradle tasks classes?

Tags: java, class, groovy, gradle, task

For creating **Gradle's** custom task classes does it matter which language we will use - Java or Groovy?

For example if I want to create *GreetingTask*.**groovy** or *GreetingTask*.**java**?
If there any considerations  of prefer one over the other - performance or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) to creating custom tasks in Gradle:

> You can implement a custom task class in pretty much any language you like, provided it ends up compiled to bytecode.

It goes on to say that the easiest option is to use Groovy because the Gradle API was designed to work well with Groovy although you could use other languages such as Java or Scala.